# How do I use Oracle schema names in Pony ORM?

Tags: python, oracle11g, ponyorm

This is the query that I need:

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.LOT
```

Using the following Python code

```
class Lot(db.Entity):
    _table_ = 'SCHEMA.LOT'
    lot_key = PrimaryKey(int)
    lot_id = Required(str)
```

this is the query that Pony ORM generates:

```
SELECT "l"."LOT_KEY", "l"."LOT_ID"
FROM "SCHEMA.LOT" "l"
```

Which naturally errors out with `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`, because Oracle thinks that `SCHEMA.LOT` is the full table name. What I really need is for Pony ORM to generate a combination of the schema and the table name delimited by a dot that is not part of the string. So any of the following will work:

```
"SCHEMA"."LOT"
"SCHEMA".LOT
SCHEMA."LOT"
```

I've tried to trick Pony ORM by defining `_table_` as `'SCHEMA"."LOT'`, but it just automatically converts this into the broken `"SCHEMA"".""LOT"`. Infuriating!

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PonyORM does this because the dot is a valid name symbol.

In order to specify compound name you need to define table name as a list of strings:

```
class Lot(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ['SCHEMA', 'LOT']
    lot_key = PrimaryKey(int)
    lot_id = Required(str)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you, Alexander. Is there documentation for this? Now that I know what to look for, I've found one other GitHub question with this answer; but I can't find this documented anywhere.